# i can't test the android wear sdk

Tags: java, android, eclipse, wear-os

I'm trying to launch a test app with Eclipse on Android Wear, but when i create a new projet, a part of Android Wear is not here. I get messages like :

WatchActivity cannot be resolved to a type (java file)

error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'roundLayout' in package (xml file)

error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'rectLayout' in package (xml file)

I've installed all SDK, and update to ADT 23.

Comment: my problem is not setting up the watch, so i can receive notification, i already did it when there was the preview sdk, but yesterday, there was a new sdk (full one)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to add the Android Wear Support library (android.support.wearable)to your workspace. Here the full steps on how to build android wear app using eclipse. Hope it will help.

https://medium.com/@tangtungai/how-to-develop-and-package-android-wear-app-using-eclipse-ef1b34126a5d

Answer (score 1):

As of the time I'm writing this, I don't think the support library contains `WatchActivity` try changing it to `Activity` and removing the corresponding import statement, and you should be good to go.

Helpful links: http://developer.android.com/preview/google-play-services-wear.html
http://developer.android.com/training/building-wearables.html
https://plus.google.com/u/0/communities/113381227473021565406

Answer (score 1):

According to http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/index.html, the Standard way to build an APP on Android Wear should be using Android Studio instead of Eclipse ADT. That may solve your error on No resource identifier (where the two file could be automatically created by Android Studio). Besides, in the newest version of Android Studio (0.8.1), WatchActivity is indeed being abandon as the default Activity for Wear application and normal Activity is used instead.